# Python code mistake resulting in no return(pitagorean set problem)

Tags: python

I am just starting out with programming in python and programming in general.
I've made this code:

```
for a in range(1,1001):
  for b in range(1,1001):
    c2=(a**2)+(b**2)
    c=c2**0.5
    if type(c) == int and a+b+c == 1000:
        print(a*b*c)
```

To find a pitagorean set with a+b+c=1000, but had no return. Code runs but doesn't print out anything and ends.
This is a euler9 problem, and I know I can find solutions on the internet but i really want to understand why this particular one that I came up with doesn't work. In my understanding it should check every pair of a and b in range of 1000 and check if for any "a^2+b^2=c^2", square root of c is an integer and a+b+c=1000.
Thanks for help

Comment: The type of c will not be an integer. It will be a float in both python 2 and 3. ```>>> type(4 ** .5)
<class 'float'>``` That's why your code isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1) The type of `c` will *always* be a float. So, `type(c) == int` will always evaluate to `False`, and your print statement will never be hit. The reason for this is because your *power* is a float. In general, square roots are only sanely represented as floats.

2) You almost never want to check the type of a variable in Python, and your case is no exception. What you want to do is check whether or not `c` has a *value* that is an integer, not if the *type* of `c` is an integer. To do that, use the built-in `is_integer`. Here's an example:

```
>>> x = 1 ** .5
>>> x
1.0
>>> x.is_integer()
True
>>> y = 2 ** .5
>>> y
1.4142135623730951
>>> y.is_integer()
False
>>> (4**.5).is_integer()
True
>>> (19**.5).is_integer()
False
>>> (25**.5).is_integer()
True
```

HTH, good luck solving the problem.

P.S. It's Pythagorean, not Pitagorean.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set c as a result of 1000-a-b this should be an integer.Than compare power of c with a^2 + b^2. As you are trying to make a square root in general it doesn't give an integer so the type of this is always float. If you remove comparing c type with int your code should work. 
If you want to check if the value is an integer you should try build in function is_integer().
`c.is_integer()`